# How to display repeated drop down based on button selection in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to display a drop down along with <kbd>Plus</kbd> button at first time. Based on button click it should display one more combination , I mean same drop down with options excluded previous selected value which we have from the first drop down and the <kbd>plus</kbd> button. This action should be repeat based on <kbd>plus</kbd> button selection.

**Here is my code:**

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.display = false;
  };

  $scope.init();

  $scope.records = [
    { id: "part1",  part: "Frt Bumper Cover" },
    { id: "part2",  part: "Frt Lwr Bumper Cover" },
    { id: "part3",  part: "Frt Upr Bumper Cover" },
    { id: "part4",  part: "Hood Panel" },
  ];

  $scope.changedValue = function(key) {
    // alert(key);
    //var index = $scope.records.indexOf(item);
    //alert(index);
    $scope.records.splice(index, 1);

    //delete $scope.records[key];
    // alert(JSON.stringify($scope.records));
  };

  $scope.sample = function() {

    $scope.display = true;
    // alert("sample: "+$scope.display);
    //alert("inside sample:::"+JSON.stringify($scope.records));
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="init()">
  <div>
    <select ng-model="selectedRecord"
            ng-change="changedValue(selectedRecord)"
            ng-options="record.id as record.part for record in records">
      <option ng-repeat="x in records">{{x.part}}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="+" ng-show="records.length!=1"
           ng-click="sample()" />
  </div>

  <div ng-show="display">
    <select ng-model="selectedRecord"
            ng-change="changedValue(selectedRecord)"
            ng-options="record.id as record.part for record in records"> 
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="+" ng-show="records.length!=1"
           ng-click="sample()" />
  </div>
</body>
```

I am unable to display like that, please share your ideas to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, i think i have a solution for your problem. :D

Its very basic code i think, so i would be happy to explain more in depth if needed.

look code here: [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/XBcMoO0g4KIzNb5uPSDo?p=preview), this is basically all the code, so its my first plunker.

```
$scope.originalRecords = [
  { id: "part1",  part: "Frt Bumper Cover" },
  { id: "part2",  part: "Frt Lwr Bumper Cover" },
  { id: "part3",  part: "Frt Upr Bumper Cover" },
  { id: "part4",  part: "Hood Panel" },
];

$scope.selectArray = [{selectedOption: null, options: $scope.originalRecords}];

$scope.selectedOption =[];

$scope.hideButton = false;

$scope.addNewSelect = function (arrayToSearch, selectedOption) {
  var index = arrayToSearch.map(function(d) { return d['part'];}).indexOf(selectedOption);
  var newRecords = arrayToSearch.slice();
  newRecords.splice(index, 1);
  if (newRecords.length > 0) {
    $scope.selectArray.push({selectedOption: null, options: newRecords});
  } else {
    $scope.hideButton = true;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot my dear friend @Meiker .. It's working as expected.